# make email viewable as webpage

Tags: html, json, email, html-email

I've made an email, but of course it won't display properly in all email programs. To make one of those "Email not displaying correctly? View online" links, should I just save a copy on my server of the email (which has user specific dynamic content) every time a user places and order (which produces the email), so I can just give the `<a>` tag an href with some unique identifier? Or should I somehow include the oringnal JSON string I made the email from within the email (hidden input or something), and somehow pass that to a generic page which can parse it and then display it properly? Which I'm not even sure is possible. It is a very, very long string.

Thanks for your input!

Comment: Don't use the JSON approach, it seems like it would enable XSS attacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first hunch sounds ideal.

Host the email online somewhere, link "View online" to the that page.

Comment: how could I provide secure access to that? Would I have to make it use a login script, or should I pass some unique string to the email so that it would be impossible to guess what the url of any given saved file would be? Login is not a problem, but it is sort of annoying for the user. Thanks!

Comment: @thomas You could obfuscate the address, but does it really need to be hidden?

Comment: Well, I mean it's detailed information about a user's order. No CC info or anything. Actually, you are probably absolutely right. Thanks.

Comment: @thomas If you decide that the order information should be confidential, then you might want to consider a link that instead says "Email not displaying correctly? Log into your account to see the order details" and link to a secure part of your site that does require authentication.

Comment: @thomas No problem! Also, be sure that you do send a plain-text version of the email along with the HTML version. You can package both in one email and it is very handy for non-visual email clients, for viewing of email content when HTML appears broken, or for people who choose to not use HTML email.

Comment: Yikes. Didn't think about that. Do you have a link that could show me how to do so with php `mail()` function?

Comment: I got some good hits from a [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+mail+html+and+plain+text) such as [this nice forum post](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=142893).

Answer (score 1):

Just so you are aware, there is this great site [here](http://inlinestyler.torchboxapps.com/styler/) that will transform external stylesheets and internal stylesheets into inline style, as well as let you know how compatible the css is with different mobile email clients. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Using special designed email is a risk. There are too many email clients/services that making a real compatible version of the email is almost impossible.

That's why you should design your emails carefully and make them simple as possible (of course without damaging UX).

Anyways, to make sure everyone will see it properly you should add "View online" link for an external html page. JSON approach is irrelevant.

Comment: Aha. yes. It's just tables with every style defined and redefined in basically every html tag. Thanks for the tip!